# split float value in two columns of mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I've wrongly entered 2 values in one column of type "VARCHAR" in this format 
value1.value2  (float value format) e.g 5.10, 4.0, 3.11 etc

Now I want to split these two values into two separate columns, of type "INT"
I've created columns and I just need a query.

I don't know how write a query to split the values of one column and update the other columns.
Anyone who knows, Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do in MySQL:

```
select cast(substring_index(varcharcol, '.', 1) as unsigned) as val1,
       cast(substring_index(varcharcol, '.', -1) as unsigned) as val2
```

EDIT:

If you want to, you can also do this in an `update`:

```
update table t
    set val1 = cast(substring_index(varcharcol, '.', 1) as unsigned),
        val2 = cast(substring_index(varcharcol, '.', -1) as unsigned)
```